# Question about calculating cloud raditiave feedback by adjusted cloud radiative forcing

Tags: climate-change, clouds, radiative-transfer

[image: https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00382-022-06369-z]
from https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00382-022-06369-z
[image: enter link description here]
from https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00382-022-06577-7

These two formulas aim to calculate cloud radiative feedback by adjusted cloud radiative forcings. In formula (1), 'F' represents 'Effective Radiative Forcing (ERF)' , while in formula (2), it denotes 'instantaneous radiative forcing (IRF)'. Which definition is correct? IRF can be directly calculated, but ERF involves adjustments that cannot be obtained directly.

Comment: Would think it best to give us input on where the formulas come from, if nothing else, to help people looking for such things?

Comment: Sorry. The two formulas are from https://doi.org/10.1007/s00382-022-06369-z and https://doi.org/10.1007/s00382-022-06577-7